# why does UIButton not show with gradient

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, ios-simulator

Hi I am new to Swift and Xcode and just learning the basics. I have added a gradient layer programmatically and then added a `UIButton` using the main storyboard and assigned an outlet to it but then when I run the code the gradient layer shows but the button shows, However, when I remove the gradient layer then the `UIButton` shows. Attached are a screenshot of what happens when both gradient and code are used and a will be attached.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let layer = CAGradientLayer()

    @IBOutlet weak var pressMeButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        layer.frame = view.bounds
        layer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor(red: 128/255, green: 206/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1).cgColor]
        layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.4)
        view.layer.addSublayer(layer)

        pressMeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
        pressMeButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
        pressMeButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        pressMeButton.setTitle("Press Me", for: .normal)
        pressMeButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

The code with the storyboard showing button placement and simulator without button:

[image: screen snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

You are adding layer on top of view, while you have added UIButton before hand. So the layer overlaps the UIButton.

You need to add a container view in the main view of controller and then add the gradient layer over it.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the gradient layer is placed on top of the button. The secondary issue (which you haven’t mentioned yet) is that if you rotate the device, it won’t respond to changes in the frame.

The best solution is to define a `GradientView` whose backing layer, dictated by its [`layerClass`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622626-layerclass), is a `CAGradientLayer`. That way (a) it will alway be below the button; and (b) it will automatically adjust to `frame` changes (and will do so gracefully more gracefully during animations than `layoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` approaches, too):

```
@IBDesignable
class GradientView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }
    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { return layer as! CAGradientLayer }

    @IBInspectable var startColor: UIColor = .white { didSet { updateGradient() } }
    @IBInspectable var endColor:   UIColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5019607843, green: 0.8078431373, blue: 1, alpha: 1)     { didSet { updateGradient() } }
    @IBInspectable var startPoint: CGFloat = 0      { didSet { updateGradient() } }
    @IBInspectable var endPoint:   CGFloat = 0.4    { didSet { updateGradient() } }


    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        updateGradient()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        updateGradient()
    }
}

private extension GradientView {
    func updateGradient() {
        gradientLayer.colors = [startColor, endColor].map { $0.cgColor }
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: startPoint)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: endPoint)
    }
}
```

With this `@IBDesignable` class, you can then set the base class for your view controller’s view to be `GradientView`, and it will render it below the button and will be correctly displayed in Interface Builder. For example, click on the background view and go to the “Identity Inspector” tab in the rightmost panel and set the “Class” in the “Custom Class” section:

[image]

You can change the start/end colors and start/end points right in IB if you want, by selecting the “Attributes Inspector” panel on the right:

[image]

Obviously, if you do this way, then you don’t have to play around with the view’s layer in `viewDidLoad` at all. But if you want to change it programmatically, you can do things like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = view as? GradientView {
        view.startColor = .black
        view.endColor = .red
    }
}
```

But I’d personally set the colors (or whatever) right in IB. And I’d keep all of the “view configuration” code in the `UIView` class, where it belongs, rather than in the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help but ultimately I created a glass with the parameters to do the gradient and another glass with the parameters for certain colours and was then able to pull them into the viewLoad.